# how to sort array in ruby if i have nil object inside array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

how to sort array if i have array like this in ruby?

example :

```
my_array = ["12 months", "13 months", nil, nil, "12"]
```

i want get result like this :

```
 my_array = ["12", "12 months", "13 months", nil, nil]
```

when i try :

```
my_array.sort{|x, y| x <=> y}
```

i get error like this :

```
ArgumentError Exception: comparison of String with nil failed
```

how to fix it?

thanks before

Comment: if you don't need nil. then do `my_array.compact` and then `sort` it as normal.

Comment: Does the array only consist of strings and `nil`? What is the criteria for sorting?

Comment: Further to @G.B.'s suggestion, one could `compact`, `sort` and then put the `nil`s back in: `s = my_array.compact.sort`, `s = s + (my_array-s) #=> ["12", "12 months", "13 months", nil, nil]`.  (The second statement could instead be `s = s + [nil]*(my_array.size-s.size)`.

Comment: What is your comparison logic? It's not at all clear from your question. E.g. Why does "12 months" come before "13 months" but "12" comes after "13 months"?

Comment: sorry my mistake, i have already edit my questions... thanks @JörgWMittag

Comment: Now I am getting even more confused. How does the string "12" get transformed to the integer 12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the nil, this will get you close...

```
2.1.2 :010 > my_array.sort { |x,y| x && y ? (x <=> y) : (x ? -1 : 1) }
 => ["12", "12 months", "13 months", nil, nil]
```

It's not exact, `'12'` comes before the rest based on the `<=>` comparison.  If you want more control you'll need to have a more complex comparison block.

Comment: when using *nested* ternary operators, use *parenthesis* for better readability...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice short way to do it, but it will only work if you can come up with a string that's guaranteed to be "greater than" all the strings in the array (which was easy here):

```
my_array.sort_by { |x| x || "Z" }
=> ["12", "12 months", "13 months", nil, nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare a 2 dimensions array: whether string is nil & the string itself.

```rb
my_array = ["12 months", "13 months", nil, nil, "12"]

my_array.sort_by { |x| [x ? 0 : 1, x] }
=> ["12", "12 months", "13 months", nil, nil]
```